# What should overloaded QAbstractItemModel::flags return for non valid QModelIndex?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I'm reading a QT documentation for a model/view architecture https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#making-the-model-editable and see an example of overloading QAbstractItemModel::flags method that returns `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` for invalid index:

```
Qt::ItemFlags StringListModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}
```

So, if index is not valid, i.e. can have negative row, we still consider that user can interact with it. Is there any sence for that logic? For me, returning `Qt::NoItemFlags` in that case could be more logical

Comment: I never had to do that. It’s not needed, a “bug” in the example: but an innocuous bug, since there’s no way to interact with items having invalid indices. So the returned value is not used. On invalid items, simply return the default value, i.e. `if (!index.isValid()) return {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `Qt::NoItemFlags`: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum.

It's the default value of the flags enum (since it's the first item in the enum). You could also write it as `return {};`, and it will give you the same `Qt::NoItemFlags`.